# How to use timeline editing with a single image input in ffmpeg?

Tags: animation, ffmpeg

Small image should be animated over a background video in a simple way:

1. change position - move along a straight line, no easing. Starting at frame A, till frame B (i.e. frames 11 to 31);
2. zoom in - between frames C and D (i.e. 45 and 55).

Filters I intend to use:

- [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1) filter has x and y parameters for image position;
- [zoompan](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#zoompan) filter allows zooming (preceeded with a static scale up to avoid jitter).

My filtergraph:

```
video.avi >----------------------------------->|-------|
                                               |overlay|-> out.mp4
image.png >-> scale >-> zoompan >-> zoompan >->|-------|
```

---

**The problem** is with [timeline editing](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing). Both filter support the `enable` option. I thought I could add instructions like `enable='between(n, 11, 31)'` to "place" the animations at right times.

Appears that the image input has only two values of `n`: zero and 1. Checked that by wrapping `n` with `print(n)` in `zoompan` filter to output during rendering.

Inside `overlay` filter, in opposite, `n` outputs sequence of numbers as expected.

---

**Question:** how can I make the single image input "look" like a normal video stream to ffmpeg filters – so that every generated frame has its unique number?

---

One of the latest tests. Video is hd720, image is 1000x200 transparent png with the logo occupying about 150x50 area in the center, not to be cropped out when zoomed in.

```
ffmpeg -i $FOOTAGE -loop 1 -i $IMAGE -filter_complex \
"
[1:v]
  scale=10*iw:-2
  ,zoompan=
    z='1'
    :x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)+80'
    :y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)'
    :d=26
    :s=500x100
    :enable='lt(print(n),24)'
  ,zoompan=
    z='min(zoom+1.3/18,2.3)'
    :x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)'
    :y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)'
    :d=20
    :s=500x100
    :enable='between(n,24,42)'
[name];
[0:v][name]
  overlay=
    x=1005-250
    :y=406-50
    :enable='lte(n,173)'
" -t 7 -y  -hide_banner  out.mp4
```

Answer (score 2):

[Appears](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/22473/how-to-keyframe-zoompan-filter-in-ffmpeg/22475?noredirect=1#comment32324_22475), `zoompan` filter does **not** support timeline editing. In commit [aa26258f](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/aa26258faa9704b144dfe5bc5d263a1332d7a9dd) dated August 27, 2017, this was updated in ffmpeg and it no longer lists zoompan as a timeline-enabled filter.

The workaround is to write expressions that depend on `in` "Input frame count" variable and output desired zoom factor.